# Remove only first duplicate value and all other matching values after comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have two array , I am trying to remove all matching value from 1st array which are in 2nd.
But if value is duplicate it should only remove 1st duplicate value.

For example - my two arrays are

```
arr1=[1,1,2,3,4,4]
arr2=[1,3,4]
```

it should give result as = `[1,2,4]`

or if my arrays are

```
arr1=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
arr2=[1,3,4]
```

it should give result as = `[1,1,2,4,4]`

I tried different approach using filter and includes but nothing works.
Below code removes all matching values but I want to remove all matching and only first duplicate value if it matches.

```
  arr1 =
    arr1.filter(f => !arr2.includes(f));
```

Comment: are these arrays already sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  this.arr2.forEach(x=>{
    if (this.arr1.indexOf(x)>=0)
      this.arr1.splice(index,1)
  })
```

or

```
  this.arr1=this.arr1.filter((x,index)=>this.arr2.indexOf(x)<0 ||
        this.arr1.indexOf(x)!=index )
```

Comment: That second solution makes my knees weak <3

Comment: To know if an element is the first occurrence (or not), in the filter we can use the second argument (the "index") and check if the index if equal to the index of the first occurrence, e.g. `this.arr1=this.arr1.filter((x,index)=>this.arr1.indexOf(x)==index )` return unique elements (well, in this case is better use reduce)

Comment: Nono, I understood it, I just wanted to let you know I found it beautiful :D

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove only the first occurrence, you can use `indexOf` instead. So, the solution would be:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  if (arr1.includes(arr2[i])) {
    let matchedItemIndex = arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]);
    arr1[matchedItemIndex] = null;
  }
}

arr1 = arr1.filter((x) => x != null);
console.log(arr1); // Expected Result: [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. Most of the above answers are right. But I would suggest using sets

```
let arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 3, 4];
let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
   let index = arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]);
   if(index > -1) {
      arr2.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     result.push(arr1[i]);
   }
}

console.log(result); /// [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` and `reduce`

```js
const process = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const set2 = new Set(arr2);
  return arr1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    set2.has(curr) ? set2.delete(curr) : acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

let arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 3, 4];
console.log(process(arr1, arr2));


arr1=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
arr2=[1,3,4]
console.log(process(arr1, arr2));
```